# Maximum number of passwords to unlock the safe

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

To open a safe, you must enter a sequence consisting of five distinct digits, with the first being the triple of the second and the last, two units smaller than the third. How many passwords, at most, should this user type to open the safe?

I know how to solve the first part.

We have passwords like:

$3--1--x--x--x;$

$6--2--x--x--x;$

$9--6--x--x--x;$

we spent two numbers on each assembly, $10 -2 = 8$ numbers left to fill each empty slot. As there are three situations, we have:

$3\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6=1008$

Now, I don't know how to finish.

May I ask for help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did not you miss 0--0--x--x--x?

Comment: Should 9--6--x--x--x be 9--3--x--x--x?

Comment: You don't seem to have obeyed the rule that the last digit must be $2$ smaller than the third.

Comment: that's true thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking about the first part is correct.

So far you have these three cases $\mathbf{(3, 1, x, x, x)}$, $\mathbf{(6, 2, x, x, x)}$, and $\mathbf{(9, 3, x, x, x)}$ that cover the first condition.

The second condition, that the last is two units smaller than the third, has these eight cases:

$\mathbf{(x, x, 2, x, 0)}$, $\mathbf{(x, x, 3, x, 1)}$, $\mathbf{(x, x, 4, x, 2)}$, $\mathbf{(x, x, 5, x, 3)}$, $\mathbf{(x, x, 6, x, 4)}$, $\mathbf{(x, x, 7, x, 5)}$, $\mathbf{(x, x, 8, x, 2)}$,  and $\mathbf{(x, x, 9, x, 7)}$

Normally in combination problems like this, you would start by multiplying the 3 possibilities for the first two digits times the 8 possibilities for the third and last digits $\mathbf {(3\times8=24).}$ However, because the problem states that you need *distinct* digits, you will realize that some of your sequences have non-distinct numbers. For example, $\mathbf{(9, 3, x, x, x)}$ and $\mathbf{(x, x, 9, x, 7)}$ would form an invalid sequence. Try to figure out how many sequences like that one you would have. Then all you have to do is factor in the fourth digit (of which there are 6 possibilities)

Comment: Thank you i will try that.